# Why is no radiation emitted during the final transmission in He-Ne laser in Ne atom?

Tags: laser, photon-emission

During the working of He-Ne laser, I have understood everything except for the fact that no radiation is emitted when the electrons go through their final transition and reach the ground state again. Why is there no emission of radiation during the final transition?

Comment: The laser action works because of electrons being in meta stable energy levels but the lower energy levels are not such states. The electrons do not stay in them for very long and hence are not there long enough to undergo stimulated emission.

Comment: Please explain and post in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following energy level diagram came from the [Wikipedia article Helium-Neon Laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium%E2%80%93neon_laser).

[image]

Electrons promoted to the $5s$ and $4s$ energy levels stay in those metastable states for much longer than electrons in the $3p$ energy level and are there long enough to allow photons of the correct energy to stimulated the transition of electrons from the $5s$ to the $3s$ state with the emission of photons which contribute to the coherent light in the visible spectrum emitted by a laser.

Once in the $3s$ state, electrons spontaneously/rapidly decay to lower energy states and emit light (fast radiative radiation) which has not been stimulated by a photons.  So light of these wavelengths is emitted but its intensity is swamped by the intensity of light emitted by stimulated emission.

Comment: Why is the light of only the wavelength 632.8 stimulated?? Why are other emissions not affected?

Comment: @uvrichest The other wavelengths are emitted but they are not in the visible part of the spectrum.

Comment: And one more thing, are all the stimulated photons released in the laser?

Comment: @uvrichest Not all the stimulated photons emitted emerge from a laser.